# No qualifying bean of type 'feign.Client' available being thrown in the background

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache, openfeign

There is an exception being thrown in the background of my application. The error is not logged but it's caught by a third-party tool called Dynatrace, due to this tool we were able to see the exception below.

We are using Java 11 and the dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.5
- spring-cloud-dependencies 2021.0.5
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-aop
- spring-cloud-starter-sleuth
- spring-cloud-starter-openfeign
- spring-boot-starter-data-redis
- spring-boot-starter-cache
- jedis
- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- spring-boot-starter-web

What I can understand from the stack trace below is that there is some issue with a @Cacheable method and the @FeignClient that is being used inside the @Cacheable method. This error only happens when there is a cache miss.

I've tried replacing the jedis with redisson but it made no difference. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "pricing-client", url = "${api.pricing.url}")
public interface PricingClient {

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<String> postRule(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorizationToken, @RequestBody PricingRequest request);

}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Message:
No qualifying bean of type 'feign.Client' available

Stacktrace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyClient.delegate(LazyClient.java:60)
org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyClient.execute(LazyClient.java:54)
feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:121)
feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:91)
feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory$1.proceed(FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory.java:66)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$$Lambda$.invoke
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:351)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$
org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignCachingInvocationHandlerFactory$$Lambda$.invoke
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy.postRule
com.custom.calc.services.CustomPricingService.getCustomRule(CustomPricingService.java:50)
com.custom.calc.services.CustomPricingService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$377e0b96.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$$Lambda$.invoke
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:421)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
com.custom.calc.services.CustomPricingService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$.getCustomRule
com.custom.calc.services.PricingResilientService.getCustomRule(PricingResilientService.java:28)
com.custom.calc.services.CalculateCustomService.calculateBalance(CalculateCustomService.java:32)
com.custom.calc.controllers.CalculateCustomController.calculateBalance(CalculateCustomController.java:35)
jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
```

Tried replacing dependencies and removing the pricing-client from feign config in application.yml

Comment: did you configure feign client in configuration properties? just wondering if this client has @ConditionalOnProperties annotation, so you're just not wiring it

Comment: @Begging I've updated the description with the feign configuration properties. The client doesn't have the `@ConditionalOnProperties` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by defining a default Client @Bean and using the FeignConfig.class as the configuration in the client

```
public class FeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public Client feignClient() {
        return new Client.Default(null, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `@EnableFeignClients` annotation to any `@Configuration` class?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Yes, we already had the `@EnableFeignClients` in a `@Configuration` class